# including 2 sound for console application(vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

i'm making a simple a game like space invader using microsoft visual basic 2010 (console.application). I am trying to make 1 background music and another as sound effect for shooting,collision and etc to work together. so far I managed to make it works by combining the following commands.However, the sound effects certainly lack of variation.Therefore, is there any better tips to improve the current state? Thank you.

(Background music)

My.Computer.Audio.Play("Game_Song.wav", AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)

(sound effect)

My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk)
or console.beep

Answer (score 0):

You can use a random number to select the play sound. Pseudo code would look like this:

```
Dim Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()

' Get a random number >= MyMin and <= MyMax
Dim random_number = Generator.Next(1, 3)

if (random_number = 1){
    My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(console.beep)
} else if (random_number = 2){
    My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk)
} else {
    My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(System.Media.SystemSounds.Comma)
}
```